# Meaning of "force" in given sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Customers have a lot on their minds; if your campaign can force one—just one!—extra thought into their memory this month, you're winning. So look at varying campaign formats. Would a postcard work better than a long-format letter? "

Answer (score 1):

The meaning here is similar to "push". See definition 3a of force (verb): http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/force

This sentence sounds a bit violent. The customers in question would probably not be happy if they heard it.